# Get css properties from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a plugin that allows the user to define the notification by typing something like this.

```
growl-top-left-300px;
```

I was using a split to get rid the width, but this still required me to have quite a few if statements because I user had the following choices

for example I had

```
if (position == "growl-top-left" || position == "growl-left-top") {
    container.css ({
        top: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    });
}else if (position == "growl-top-right" || position == "growl-right-top") {
    container.css ({
        top: '0px',
        right: '0px'
    });
}else if (position == "growl-top-center" || position == "growl-center-top") {
    // apply css // Not done yet
}else if (position == "growl-bottom-left" || position == "growl-left-bottom") {
    container.css ({
        bottom: '0px',
        left: '0px'
    });
}else if (position == "growl-bottom-right" || position == "growl-right-bottom") {
    container.css ({
        bottom: '0px',
        right: '0px'
    });
}else if (position == "growl-bottom-center" || position == "growl-center-bottom") {
    // apply css // not done yet
}
```

but as you can imagine that seems like a lot of redundant code, and I just want to know if anyone has a nicer way to clean it up?

I thought it would be nice if I could get the top and left css values so I can write the following code:

```
container.css ({
    retrivedCSS[0]: '0px',
    retrivedCSS[1]: '0px'
})
```

where retrivedCSS[0] would be the first position and the [1] would be the second position

Comment: you could just apply it as a class on the element then just use css like .growl-top-left, .growl-left-top {}

Comment: What do you have inside those `if`'s? If it has something like setting `top` and `left` for `growl-left-top`, then I have a trick ;)

Comment: I just posted an updated that shows how I apply the CSS

Comment: @Pete I want this to not use any other files than the plugin it self. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about splitting the position string and using those tokens. See below,

```
var tokens = position.split('-');

var updateCSS = {};
updateCSS[tokens[1]] = updateCSS[tokens[2]] = '0px';    

container.css (updateCSS);
```

Incase if you use more complicated string like `growl-top-center-padding` e.t.c, use an iterate.

```
var updateCSS = {};
var tokens = position.split('-');

for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
   if(tokens[i] == 'growl') continue;

   updateCSS[tokens[i]] = '0px';
}

container.css (updateCSS);
```

Comment: What does the `if (tokens[i] == 'grow') continue;` mean? Wouldn't that mean that it would skip the actual locations since `token[1]` would equal `top` and not `growl`.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh It is `token[i]`, not `token[1]`. Note the `i` (iterator)

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh: I guess Vega thought that `growl` can not possibly be part of the CSS expression.

Comment: @Amberlamps Is it part of CSS? Well, he can remove that condition if he want growl to be part of CSS. I was going by what he had inside those if conditions in his post.

Comment: @Vega the problem is that in your split the very first object would be `gorwl` not a location and following that only the second and thrid objects are going to be locations and the very last object well be a padding.

Comment: @Vega: I was not saying that it is part of CSS and I also do not think that it is.

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh In the post `if (position == "growl-top-left" || position == "growl-left-top") { container.css ({ top: '0px', left: '0px'}); }` -- The above code would work for this. Let me know if it is different. I assume the order of `top` and `left` wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Vega really the best choice here would be to remove the loop and than just write something like this `updateCSS[token[1]] = '0px'` and `updateCSS[token[2]] = '0px'` and this would remove the need for a loop at all! does that sound like it would work?

Comment: @Vega, missed your last comment, but what does the if statement do then? to me it looks like it is saying to only continue if `token[i] == 'growl'`, but this wouldn't be true once it actually hit the other objects... I think that if statement is throwing me off. I am about toy try both yours and @Amberlamps and see which works better.

Comment: @Vega with your method, I keep getting the following error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh must be a typo. It shoukd be `tokens` not `token`

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh Sorry, my fault. Must be cranky today. See fixed demo http://jsfiddle.net/xPR8c/2/

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
// map string to one key
var key = position.split("-").sort().join("-");

var map = {

    "growl-bottom-center": "your CSS",
    // ...
    "growl-right-top": "your CSS"

}

applyCSS(map[key]);
```

Comment: This might stress the engine a little more but the less lines would probably make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Use could use fallthrough switch statements, although they are still pretty ugly.

```
switch(position.split("-").sort().join("-")) {
    case 'growl-top-left': //apply css
        break;
    case 'growl-center-top': // apply css
        break;
}
```

Thanks to @Amberlamps for the brilliant suggestion on using position.split("-").sort().join("-") His full solution is absolutely better than this as well.

Comment: Why do I always forget about switch statements... Every time I tell you.  Before I mark this as the answer, I would like to see if anyone else has any other ideas, but this seems like a great solution to shorting the code.

Comment: Replace `position` with `position.split("-").sort().join("-")`. That will save you 50% of your case statements.

Comment: @Amberlamps Wouldn't that be more for the JavaScript engine to handle then just adding the one extra line per case?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh: It would probably stress the engine a bit more. But you would have less lines and the engine is very powerful after all.